# How to use .year inside function in KDB?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I would like to use dot notation to extract the year of a date.

```
q) myDate:2014.01.01;
q) myDate.year
2014i           / works OK
```

But when inside a function,

```
f:{[x] :x.year};
f[myDate]
```

I get an error (I use Studio for KDB+)

```
An error occurred during execution of the query.
The server sent the response:
x.year
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this page on code.kx](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/2_Basic_Data_Types_Atoms/#257-constituents-and-dot-notation), this behavior is a quirk of q. To get around this, you can use the cast function.

```
q)f:{[x] :`year$x}
q)f[myDate]
2014i
```